# Every finite dimensional Banach-space is reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis, reflexive-space

I have to prove that every finite dimensional Banach space is reflexive. The text suggests me to use the fact that every N-dimensional space is linearly isomorphic to $ \mathbb{R}^N $, and that if two spaces $ X,Y $ are linearly isomorphic, then if one is reflexive then the other one is reflexive. So I need to prove that $ (\mathbb{R}^N, ||\cdot||_2) $ is reflexive. In the following, $X^*$ is the space of the linear and bounded operators over $X$ and $X^{**} $ means $ (X^*)^*$. I tried the following way.
I have to prove that the canonical map: \begin{align} & \tau:\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^N)^{**} \text{ s.t. } \\ & \tau(x)=\Lambda_x \text{ , where } \Lambda_xL=Lx \ \ \forall L\in (\mathbb{R}^N)^* \end{align}
is surjective. That is, I have to show that every $\Lambda \in (\mathbb{R}^N)^{**} $ is a $\Lambda_x$. So, fix $ \Lambda \in (\mathbb{R}^N)^{**} $ .
$ \text{Since } \mathbb{R}^N \text{is isomorphic to } (\mathbb{R}^N)^* \text{there exists a N-dimensional basis of } (\mathbb{R}^N)^*.\\ \text{So, I call this base } B=\{B_i\}_{i=1,..,N}. \text{Set } L \in (\mathbb{R}^N)^*. \text{I have } \Lambda L=\Lambda( \sum_{i=1}^{N} \alpha_iBi)=\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_{i}\Lambda(B_i). \text{Let's call } b_\Lambda=(\Lambda(B_1),...,\Lambda(B_N)) \text{ and } \alpha_L=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n). \text{Since } L= \sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_{i}B_i, \text{ I have} Lx= \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_{i} B_i(x).\text{I set } b_L(x)=(B_1(x),...,B_N(x)) \text{. Now I should prove that there exists an x s.t. } b_\Lambda=b_L(x). $

I have to say I'm a bit confused here. I don't know if this is the right approach. Besides I don't understand how the fact that I'm considering $ \mathbb{R}^N $ and not any other finite dimensional space should help me in the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Try instead to prove that $$\dim(\mathbb R^N)^*=N$$

Once you prove this, look at the picture:
$$ \tau:\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^N)^{**}$$
you have $\dim(\tau( \mathbb{R}^N))=N= \dim( (\mathbb{R}^N)^{**})$.

What can you say about a subspace of $\mathbb R^N$ of dimension $N$?

**Hint 2:** Let $v_1,..,v_N$ be a basis in $\mathbb R^N$. For each $1 \leq j \leq N$ show that there exists some $f_j \in (\mathbb R^N)^*$ such that
$$\begin{align} f_j(v_j)=1 &  \\ f_j(v_i)=0 & \forall i \neq j  \end{align}$$

Prove that $f_1,.., f_N$ is a basis in $\mathbb R^N$.

**Hint 3** If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and $\dim(W)=\dim(V)$ show that $V=W$.

To do this use the fact that every basis of $W$ can be completed to a basis of $V$.

Now, use this with $\tau(\mathbb R^N) \subseteq (\mathbb{R}^N)^{**}$ to deduce that 
$$\tau(\mathbb R^N) = (\mathbb{R}^N)^{**}$$
meaning that $\tau$ is surjective, which is exactly what you need to show.

Comment: Thanks for the hints.For the hint 1: $dim((\mathbb{R}^N)^*)=N$ follows from the fact that $(\mathbb{R}^N)^*$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^N$  but why this imply the rest?

Comment: I came up to this. Since $dim(\tau(\mathbb{R}^N))=N=dim((\mathbb{R}^N)^{**})$, then the two space are isomorphic. In particular a basis for $\tau(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is a  basis for $(\mathbb{R}^N)^{**}$. So if $\Lambda \in (\mathbb{R}^N)^{*}$ then $\Lambda L=\sum a_j \Lambda_{x_j}L =\sum a_jL(x_j)=L(\sum a_j x_j)$ Is this enough? I don't understand how to use your second hint, and still I don't understand for what I need $dim(\mathbb(R)^N)^*=N$. I think in your second hint you meant $f_j(v_j) \ne 0$.

Comment: @Peanojr Isomorphic is NOT enough, to be reflexive you need to show that $\tau$ is onto. The key here is that if a subspace $W \subseteq V$ has the same finite dimension then $W=V$.

Comment: @Peanojr and yes you are right about the second hint.

Comment: @Peanojr See hint $3$... What I was hinting towards is the following :You know that $\tau(\mathbb R^N) \subseteq (\mathbb{R}^N)^{**}$ and you need to deduce that $\tau(\mathbb R^N) = (\mathbb{R}^N)^{**}$. Since you are in the finite dimensional case, all you need to do is prove that they have the same dimension. Note that the inclusion is essential, the image being isomorphic to the second dual is not enough in the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: If I know that $ W \subseteq V$, and $dim(W)=dim(V)=N$, then a basis for W is also a basis for V, since the basis of W belongs to V and has N elements so is maximal. Since they have the same basis they coincide. Is this okay? But I find more difficult to prove that $dim(\tau (\mathbb{R}^N))=dim((\mathbb{R}^N)^{**})$. If I'm not wrong, $ dim(\tau(\mathbb{R}^N))=N $ since $ \tau $ is an isomorphism and the image of the basis through an isomorphism is still a basis. I can prove this. Now is $ dim((\mathbb{R}^N)^{**}) \le N $ obvious? If I prove this I can conclude, right?

Comment: Well, that should be true, since I can prove that $X^*$ is isomorphic to $X$, so they have the same dimension. To prove that, I just have to fix a basis and show that every linear function can be written as a $Lx=<x,\alpha_L> \forall x \in X$, where $\alpha$ is the image of the basis through L, and show that $J:L \rightarrow \alpha_L$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Peanojr Well, that is exactly what Hint 2 is about: given a basis $v_1,..,,v_N$ for $X$, the set $f_1,.., f_N$ forms a basis for $X^*$. Therefore $\dim(X^*)=N$. This shows that $\dim(X)=\dim(X^*)$. Applying this one more time gives you what you want... And yes, Hint 2 is similar to the strategy from your comment.

Comment: @Peanojr To make this crystal clear, once you prove that $\dim(Y)=\dim(Y^*)$ for each finite dimensional vector space $Y$, applying this first for $Y=X$ and then for $Y=X^*$ gives you $$\dim(X^*)=\dim(X) \\ \dim(X^{**})=\dim(X^*)$$

Comment: Yes, I got that now. Thank you really much for your time!